# Node content versioning and compare tool

Tags: nodes, version-control

I already know that node content versioning is supported in drupal, what I want to know is how much?

I for instance create a content type 'article' and add some extra text fields to it, The article content should have the capability to be reviewed and altered by many authors/reviewers and their changes will be saved as seperate records not impacting the real article record, only if I approve their changes will they be reflected on main article record.

Which of the functionality is currently supported and what is not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Revisioning](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning) module for comparisons of different revisions:

> Revisioning is a module for the configuration of workflows to create,
>   moderate and publish content revisions.

or you can use [Diff](https://www.drupal.org/project/diff) module:

> This module adds a tab for sufficiently permissioned users. The tab
>   shows all revisions like standard Drupal but it also allows pretty
>   viewing of all added/changed/deleted words between revisions.